# How could I extract the text under <div> and <ul> class using Selenium Java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I want to extract the text "Hi, Harvey " from the below html source

```
<div class="col-sm-9>
 <div class="shop-menu">
  <ul clas="navbar-nav">
    ::before
     "Hi, harvey "
      <a href="logout.htm">..</a>
     ::after
   </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Hi, harvey "))
```

but couldn't extract it, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should locate that element

```java
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[contains(.,'Hi, harvey')]"))
```